# Canon Software: Live Internet Connection for WiFi-based Transfer?

Tags: canon, software, powershot, wifi

Canon Utilities Image Transfer Utility Version 1.2.1.8 allows me to transfer photos to my computer successfully via wifi.  But if the computer does not have an Internet connection, it fails to connect through WiFi.  Specifically, I get to the "Connected device:" message on the camera, with the computer name, but after waiting, I get a "Connection Failed" message.

If I am only moving images from the local camera, to the local computer via wifi, why is an Internet connection required?

Are other people experiencing this?  If so, does it bother you?  What if you're traveling and need to unload your camera to your laptop so you can take more pictures?  Do you think this is a software bug?  If so, how are bugs like this reported?  Is there a work-around?

Additional information:

1) network landscape: An Ethernet LAN is wired to the computer and also wired to the WiFi access point.  When an 802.11 WLAN radio connection is made by the camera, it is also on the LAN, and lists the computers it "sees".  This all works fine.  This is not a networking issue.

2) Of course I could use a USB cable, but I paid more for a WiFi camera and would like to have the benefits.

Comment: When traveling with a laptop and doing a batch transfer as you seem to be describing, an USB cable is by far the easiest workaround. What camera are you using? Does it have a mini/micro USB port?

Comment: In your offline case, are you still connecting the "same way"; e.g. both devices connect to a wifi access point, or camera acting as a Direct server and the laptop tunes into that?  If the former... well, let's find out the details first.

Comment: Do you have the cables that should have came with the camera?
Use the one with USB Connector and upload your images thatway no wifi required.

Comment: one of the devices (computer or camera) needs to be in access-point mode or both need to be in adhoc mode for wi-fi to connect

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I see you also [posted at Canon's support site](http://community.usa.canon.com/t5/PowerShot/Live-Internet-Connection-for-WiFi-based-Transfer/td-p/152270) and conversed briefly with them. It sounds like this Canon software is *really* poorly designed. See also [similar discussion at dpreview.com](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3588666)

Comment: No solution from Canon either.

Comment: Wifi file transfer isn't really a benefit, especially if the card is full, unless you plan to leave it copying overnight. I tried wifi copy once, then removed the card and used a card reader on the laptop

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this with my Canon 77D and EOS Utility 3.7.0 for Windows - everything works without an issue even if there isn't any Internet available. So it seems that this bug was fixed in later versions of the software.